# Change an image SRC on parent page when a fancybox is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, fancybox

I have an .aspx (ASP.Net VB) page in an iframe fancybox that I use to upload an image. I then store the image name as a session variable, eg;

```
session("imageName")
```

The fancybox is still open at this point.

Now, when I close that fancybox I want to update an IMG's src on the parent page;

```
<IMG SRC="dave.jpg" ID="fooImage">
```

I would assume that i can use the parent's fancybox `"onClosed"` function to 
do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your OnClosed method

```
function onClosed(){
    var Src= document.getElementById('fooImage');
    document.getElementById('fooImage').src = Src;
}
```

Comment: Actually what you have done there is got the current image src, and replaced it with itself!

Comment: var Src= document.getElementById('ID');
this ID is actually the input field or src fieldin popup..

Comment: HTML of Popup will also be on same page so you can get value in popup input field by 
 var Src = document.getElementById('yourID')

and then replace it with your image src

Comment: yes if the popup was a DIV, but this isnt going to work for an iframe fancybox. I will post the answer later.